# Cannot install Clang on Archlinux

Tags: installation, clang, virtual-machine, archlinux

For my second year we need to learn how to use linux (at a beginner level) and our professor told us to use Ubuntu, or ArchLinux if we wanted to learn more. I installed ubuntu and the required tools (he gave us a short list) but Archlinux freeze completly when I try to install clang and I have to recreate a new Virtual machine (I am on a Mac using VMWare) each time

here is the list of tool needed:

- emacs
- clang (>=3.4)
- gcc (>= 4.8)
- make
- xterm

For each one it works but for clang

Here is the error I get:

[image http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/876673ScreenShot20140906at182459.png](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/876673ScreenShot20140906at182459.png)

and it doesn't respond anymore so I have to forcequit my VM and reinstall a new one. **Has anybody already encountered this error ? Does anybody know what it means ?** I tried pacman -Syu but it has not done anything...

Thank you

Comment: Have you verified you have enough drive space?

Comment: Only other thing I'd consider looking at is running some sort of drive check on your Mac's hard drive. Could be bad sectors on your Mac's hard drive that have propagated as errors into the VM

Comment: I can choose the disk space and put 15GB for this VM ( which I think is way enough). Hum okay I will check that

Comment: Is that still valid question? If no, then please put resolution in answers.

Comment: I never managed to install it no, so yes, it still is valid.

Answer (score 0):

First It looks like a error that your VM hard drive is broken.
But it just 'maybe'.
Try to reboot it and try install commands again.
If it still can't work try to add `-o $(pidof mount.ntfs-3g)` to `kill_all_wait()` in `/etc/rc.d/functions` and reboot it.